# How to send list of linq results to ajax c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, linq

What i'm trying to do is, return a List of items trhough linq query in items object and then send it to json, but I don't know what am i doing wrong:

```
  public ActionResult editarComanda(int idcomanda)
        {

            List<Items> objectes = new List<Items>();
            var db = new daw_tenda();

              var llistaobjectes =  db.Llistes.Where(x => x.comandes_id == idcomanda).ToList();

                foreach (var item in llistaobjectes)
                {
                   **objectes.Add(db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == item.items_id).ToList());**   

                }
                return Json(objectes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

How to add to objectes the result from that linq query?

This is my Ajax script:

```
  $(".editar").click(function () {  //BUTO editar comanda
                                var itemid = $(this).attr('id');
                                $("#contingutllistes").empty();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/Perfil/editarComanda",
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        idcomanda: itemid,
                                    },
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        console.log(response);
                                        if (response) {
                                            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                             ???

                                            }
                                            $("#contingutllistes").show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                            });
```

Comment: can you add your javascript method which handles the JSON response? Also, what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method `AddRange` on `objectes` like so:

```
foreach (var item in llistaobjectes)
{
    objectes.AddRange(db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == item.items_id).ToList());
}
```

You could also use `objectes.Add(db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == item.items_id).FirstOrDefault())`, but I'm not sure what your database structure is, so that may not work.

**Serializing Entity Framework Objects**

You cannot serialize directly entity framework objects because the navigation properties will result in circular references. You have two options:

1. Use a `Select(x => new { ... })` to create an anonymous object that you will return instead of returning your `Item` object.
2. Create a class that does nothing but hold the values you want to send for `Item`. This is called the DTO pattern and IMO is the better option.

Option 1 will get you going, but option 2 will be more maintainable.

Here is an example of option 1 so that you can get started:

```
foreach (var item in llistaobjectes)
{
    objectes.AddRange(db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == item.items_id).Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            SKU = x.SKU, //No idea what your table looks like
            AnotherProperty = x.AnotherProperty, //again, no idea...
        }).ToList());
}
```

**Performance**

But I'm going to tell you right now, that performance will not be good. What you should do is to replace your method with something like:

```
public ActionResult editarComanda(int idcomanda)
{
    var db = new daw_tenda();



    var llistaIds =  db.Llistes.Where(x => x.comandes_id == idcomanda)
        .Select(x => x.items_id)
        .ToList();

    var objectes = db.Items.Where(x => llistaIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
    return Json(objectes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This executes exactly two database queries. Your previous one would execute a database query for every id. This new one first loads the ids and then loads your items. The second query actually creates a `WHERE IN` SQL query (that's what `Contains` in a `Where` will create in most cases when the containing list is a list of strings or ints or something) which should perform reasonably well for moderately sized lists.

**Aside**

This isn't part of my answer, but have you tried looking at [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for MVC4/5? I used to use MVC for doing JSON, but it does weird things with stuff like timestamps and is hard to use overall. Web API would probably work better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: That outputs me a reference circular object

Comment: Ah. You are serializing database entities. One moment while I fix that.

Comment: I'm adding the Items Object to the post.. takes  a while, so i MUST select every single column from the query? If i select the tables that have a referenced key to other table, that might cause a reference circular too, so the best option i guess is to create a single object for this query with the columns i want right?
I'm actually working on MVC4

Comment: objectes.AddRange(db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == item.items_id).Select(x => new{preu x.preu, titol = x.titol, id = x.Id, imatge = x.imatge, descripcio = x.descripcio }).ToList();   
output: got some invalid arguments. I created a class only for this query with those columns.

Comment: Yes you will need to create an object with the columns you want, but you're query will will need to be in terms of the database objects so you will need to convert from then to the other object via a select. Serializing entity framework objects simply won't work unless you get rid of all of your navigation properties.